# Dynamically placing empty space

Tags: html

I have some dynamic content which covers up to 3 page and I want to display in a specific format. For that I need to place a empty divs in bottom of each page to cover up remaining spaces and start my remaining content from new page always. This pages later converted in to a pdf page.

My issue is I don't how many blank space I need to insert in all cases, since the content size change always. Is there a way to dynamically see how much space is left from page bottom and print blank spaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of manually adding spaces to your document, you should use the `page-break-before`, `page-break-after`, or `page-break-inside` CSS rules to tell the user agent how it should break up pages.

See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-breaks